# scrollcontroller doesn't work with futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

i have an api call that upload data by offset, my goal is to load 10 by 10 on user scroll down, the problem is that i can't scroll down and show more data: here is my snippets:

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          HomeHeader(),
          ProductsGridViewInfiniteScroll(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the scrollcontroller seems doesn't work:

```
class ProductsGridViewInfiniteScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ProductsGridViewInfiniteScrollState();
  }
}

class ProductsGridViewInfiniteScrollState
    extends State<ProductsGridViewInfiniteScroll> {
  Future<ProductList> products;
  int offset;
  ScrollController _controller;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        offset += 10;
        products = loadProductsByIdService(1, offset, 10);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    offset = 0;
    products = loadProductsByIdService(1, offset, 10);
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<ProductList>(
        future: products,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return GridView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.products.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: ProductCard(product: snapshot.data.products[index]),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return SizedBox();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

```
Future<ProductList> loadProductsByIdService(serviceid, offset, limit) async {
  var datamap = {'service_id': serviceid, 'offset': offset, 'limit': limit};
  var data = json.encode(datamap);
  ProductList products;

  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(PRODUCTS),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body: data,
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));

  if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      products = ProductList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
  } else {
    throw Exception('echec de chargement des produits');
  }

  return products;
}
```

i want to rebuild the build function and update the products variable every time the scroll reaches the bottom of the screeen, any help please;

Comment: Did you restarted the app? When we define controllers, the app needs a restart. Please check if setState is executed.

Comment: i restarted the app as you said but just 10 products that are loaded when scrolling down nothing happen, if you don't mind how can i check if setState is executed or not?

Comment: do a print("something") which should print something in terminal.

Comment: is any product shown at all?

Comment: yes just the first 10 products

Comment: the setState seems not working too

Comment: Is print called if you place it at the beginning of _scrollListener. Maybe the if condition has problems.

Comment: i replaced the condition above with this condition but nothing happening  `if(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent == _controller.position.pixels)`

Comment: If you place the print outside the if, is it printed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [ClampingScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClampingScrollPhysics-class.html) is the default behavior of scroll physics in Android and [BouncingScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BouncingScrollPhysics-class.html).
Most probably you are running on IOS so by default you  are using BouncingScrollPhysics. If that is the case, please change your if condition to:

```
_scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        _controller.position.outOfRange) {
      _controller.jumpTo(0);
      setState(() {
        offset += 10;
        products = getProducts(offset, limit);
      });
    }
  }
```

When bouncing physics is used, the scrolling passes max scrolling extend and outOfRange becomes true.
You need to reset controller offset back to 0 as it will keep calling the listener multiple times which skips pages by increasing offset.

Comment: actually i am using chrome for debugging, am asking if on a real device it can work? your solution also not working

Comment: @ELHITFatima I am sorry but I have tested it in my Android device. It works!

Comment: yeah i am working on a computer that does not support virtualization, so i can't run the app on an emulator, thnx i am going to tested on another computer

Comment: @ELHITFatima you may try to set physics to BouncingScrollPhysics because my answer is adapted for these kind of physics.

Comment: @eduardHasanag actually it works ` physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),` with shrinkwrap setting to true, i also fixed the problem without scrollcontroller via an index condition in the itembuilder `if (index == snapshot.data.products.length - 1 ){
                 products = loadProductsByIdService(serviceId, offset += 10, limit); }`

Answer (score 0):

if anyone have the same issue this is the final solution that worked for me without the use of FutureBuilder :

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static int offset = 0;
  ScrollController _sc = new ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  ProductList products = new ProductList(products: []);

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._getMoreData(1, offset, 10);
    super.initState();
    _sc.addListener(() {
      if (_sc.position.pixels == _sc.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _getMoreData(1, offset += 10, 10);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildGrid();
  }

  Widget __buildGrid() {
    return GridView.builder(
        controller: _sc,
        itemCount: products.products.length + 1,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
          if (index == products.products.length) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Opacity(
                  opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 00,
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              // child: Flexible(
              child: ProductCard(product: products.products[index]),
              // ),
            );
          }
        });

   
  }

  void _getMoreData(serviceid, offset, limit) async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      var datamap = {'service_id': serviceid, 'offset': offset, 'limit': limit};
      var data = json.encode(datamap);
      ProductList ps;

      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(PRODUCTS),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          },
          body: data,
          encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        ps = ProductList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          products.products.addAll(ps.products);
          // offset += 10;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```